# setting view port before loading HTML page in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, viewport, meta

I am an iOS developer and i do not have any knowledge about web development.I am trying to load an HTML page on `UIWebView` since the content size of web page is larger then the iOS device screen size,the webview shows scroll bars which has to be avoided in my case.I want to fit the page to the webview width.

I did read some posts here and understood that i should change the **viewport** of HTML to get things work as i desired.When i manually change the **width** and **height** properties of **meta** tag in HTML its fitting to my webview.What is the best method to change the view port before loading page.

(I have seen approaches to set scale using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` in `webViewDidFinishLoading:` and i can not prefer doing this because the webview takes time to load the content till then it shows the scalled page then it refreshes.)

Is there any better method to change meta propertied then reading HTML file in to `NSString` and do poor string level manipulations?The HTML pages are always available locally on the device.

Please help,i need to get it fixed as soon as possible.